# Unexpected output from recursive function

Tags: c

I am new to c programming. i wrote this program and expecting to print `0, 1, 2, 3` but it is printing `0,1,2,0`. i was learning recursion. why is this printing `0,1,2,0` please explain this step-by-step.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int);
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
int proc(pf, int, int);

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}

void fun(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        fun(--n);
        printf("%d,", n);
        fun(--n);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it prints `0, 1, 2, 3` the recurson will never end!

Comment: would you please explain ...... thanks

Comment: You can understand it your self, just call the function and write down the current value of `n` in a piece of paper.

Comment: See that code:

    void fun(int n)
    {
        if (n > 0)
        {
            fun(--n);

as a loop that doesn't print anything until `n==0`. When `n` is 0, then recursion ends and first `print` is reached.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi i tried but i am not getting it.

Comment: I suggest you put a line at the beginning of the function like this: `printf("starting fun with argument %d", n);`

Comment: When you call `fun()` from within `fun()`, you need to wait until `fun()` returns, but it then calls `fun()` again, when `n == 0`, it doesn't call `fun()` anymore, and then `printf()` is called.

Comment: As Iharob mentioned, write it down on paper. The code is so basic this should be very easy to do. You'll immediately see why it fails.

Comment: One hint: if you're providing C code here - because it is very verbose, make sure that you actually do have an MCVE; I was trying to find out where `pf` and `proc` were used - and the answer was: "nowhere"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to see that the program cannot ever print 3 is that before any fprintf can be invoked, the code must always run --n at least once, therefore the starting values cannot be printed.

To go through the code as mentioned in the comments, one can just write the functions as "blocks", as in the following pseudo-code, with the convention that an updated value of n is mutuated in the called function but of course not the other way around. Then the flow would look like:

```
{n:3--->2
    {n:2--->1
        {n:1--->0
            {n:0 ---> return}
            print(n=0)
            n:0--->-1
                {n:-1 ---> return}
        }
        print(n=1)
        n:1--->0
            {n:0 ---> return}
    }
    print(n=2)
    n:2--->1
    {n:1--->0
        {n:0 ---> return}
        print(n=0)
        n:0--->-1
        {n:-1 ---> return}
    }
}
```

That prints indeed 0, 1, 2, 0.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem come from `--n`. In fact, this is not one instruction, but two instructions, `--n` is equal to `n=n-1`. So you will never print the value you get from the function calling, but the value less one. That's why the max value you get is 2.

Then, I let you find how to solve your problem by yourself. And as @Iharob and @Zimano suggested to you, write it down on paper will help you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i am really confused with this program, i tried it on paper but failed to get it. i did.t get how it print 0 at last. please explain...